# Detecting class on HTML element not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button and when it is clicked it should add a class to the HTML element, but then when the .class is clicked, it isn't detected.

This is the use case:

- Click button - "testerclass" will be added to HTML element
- Click "testerclass" - removes that class from that element

The detection for when "testerclass" is clicked only seems to work when the class exists before the page load, not when I add the class manually after load. Is this something to do with the problem?

I have tried to recreate the problem on jsfiddle, but I can't recreate the use case where the class is already added to the HTML element, as I can't edit that on jsfiddle.

But [here is jsfiddle one](http://jsfiddle.net/t34PQ/), In this one you can see that the buttonone adds a class to HTML, but the detection for clicks on .testerclass never come through.

And [here is jsfiddle two](http://jsfiddle.net/t34PQ/1/). In this one, I have changed the .testerclass selector to `html`, and this shows that HTML clicks are bubbling through (which I was unsure of when I first hit this problem).

And offline I created a third testcase where the HTML element already had the testerclass, and it detected the clicks sent through to it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.1').click(function() {
        $('html').addClass('testerclass');
        $('.test').append('"testerclass" added to html<br />');
    });

    $('.testerclass').click(function() {
        $('.test').append('testerclass clicked and removed<br />');
        $('html').removeClass('testerclass');
    });
});
```

Edit: I also tried doing this with a slightly different method of:

```
$('html').click(function() {
    if(this).hasClass('testerclass') {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

but that didn’t work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `testerclass` is dynamic, you need to use event delegation to handle events based on that. Which will require us to register the event handler to the document object that causes another problem because the click event from the button will get propagated to the document object which will trigger the `testerclass` click handler as well. To prevent this from happening you can stop the event propagation from the button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button.1').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('html').addClass('testerclass');
        $('.test').append('"testerclass" added to html<br />');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.testerclass', function () {
        $('.test').append('testerclass clicked and removed<br />');
        $('html').removeClass('testerclass');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8Rw2n/)

Comment: Nice that works! I did try with propagation stopped on the button, but its the second selector that really does it! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the propagation to the html so the other click handler does not pick it up.

```
$('button.1').on("click", function(evt) {
    $('html').addClass('testerclass');
    $('.test').append('"testerclass" added to html<br />');
    evt.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on("click", function() {
    $('.test').append('testerclass clicked and removed<br />');
    $('html').removeClass('testerclass');
});
```

Other option would be to add one event handler and use the event target to see if it is the button or not and change the content that way.

```
$(document).on("click", function (evt) {        
    var isButton = $(evt.target).is(".btn");
    var message = isButton ? '<p>"testerclass" added to html</p>' : '<p>"testerclass" clicked and removed</p>'
    $('html').toggleClass('testerclass', isButton);
    $(".test").append(message);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/69scv/

Comment: It didn't work with just stopping the propagation, the problem wasn't that it was being removed instantly, but that the clicks to html weren't appearing at all

Comment: Well it should be document, not html

Answer (score 0):

here's a neat way to do it

```
$('html').on('click', function(e) {
    var state = !!$(e.target).closest('button.1').length;
    var msg   = state ? 'class added' : 'class removed';

    $(this).toggleClass('testerclass', state); 
    $('.test').append(msg + '<br>');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/t34PQ/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You add a class to html element, so when this class is clicked, it means the html element is click. Now the problem is when you click any where in page, it will remove this class away from html! Let try add this class to body element instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.1').click(function() {
        $('body').addClass('testerclass');
        $('.test').append('"testerclass" added to html<br />');
    });

    $('.testerclass').click(function() {
        $('.test').append('testerclass clicked and removed<br />');
        $('body').removeClass('testerclass');
    });
});
```

And now you can check it:

```
$('html').click(function() {
    if(this).hasClass('testerclass') {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```